# Passing JSON to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is my function in javascript:

```
function callRemoteService(requestId, sObjectId, bObjectId) {
$.ajax({
    url: "../../../serviceRemoteEngine.php",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    timeout: 1000,
    data: JSON.stringify({"requestId":requestId,"SOobjectId":sObjectId,"SBobjectId":bObjectId}),
    success: function(remoteResponse){
        alert(remoteResponse.msg);
    }
});
}
```

And this is `serviceRemoteEngine.php`:

```
echo json_encode(array("msg" => $_POST["SOobjectId"]));
```

The function is called with these parameters:

```
callRemoteService('remove', 15, 0)
```

The thing is that, instead of seeing `15` in alert message, `null` is displayed instead.

However, when I change PHP file into:

```
echo json_encode(array("msg" => "message"));
```

"message" text is displayed with js alert.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `JSON.stringify()`, when sending ajax-request, because `$.ajax()` function expects associative array of parameters, not string.

```
function callRemoteService(requestId, sObjectId, bObjectId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../../serviceRemoteEngine.php",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 1000,
        data: {"requestId":requestId,"SOobjectId":sObjectId,"SBobjectId":bObjectId},
        success: function(remoteResponse){
            alert(remoteResponse.msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That changes nothing... responses in both ways remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

PHP expects a post/get request to have `key=value` pairs. You're sending over a bare string, so it's just `value`. Since there's no key, PHP cannot (and will not) put anything into $_POST, since there's no key to attach the `value` to.

Try

```
data: {foo: JSON.stringify(...)}
```

and

```
echo $_POST['foo']
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP for the JSON is this:

```
echo json_encode(array("msg" => "message"));
```

But you should see if adding proper JSON headers will help clear things up. Like this:

```
$json_data = json_encode(array("msg" => "message"));
header('X-JSON: (' . $json_data . ')');
header('Content-type: application/x-json');
echo $json_data;
```

Also, reading over your question again, you seem to be wanting to get the `$_POST["SOobjectId"]` immediately & then sent that back via JSON? Are you sure that `$_POST` contains anything? In your PHP file before you do anything else, do this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or do this for the `$_REQUEST` to see if data is transmitted:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Perhaps you need to do this in your PHP file. Get the raw `$_POST` data via `file_get_contents('php://input')` and then decode it and handle it that way. All of my reworking—including this idea—below:

```
$json_decoded_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$json_data = json_encode(array("msg" => $json_decoded_array['SOobjectId']));
header('X-JSON: (' . $json_data . ')');
header('Content-type: application/x-json');
echo $json_data;
```

Comment: This code will display "message" anyway, the way my line does it. The results are the same.